# Socket switch over in clustered environment

Tags: java, sockets, jboss, cluster-computing

On a web-app running on Jboss, there is a TCP Socket connection that we use to achieve heartbeat for a session (rtsp). Till now it was doing a Client Socket binding:-

```
Socket client = new Socket(host,port);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
out.write(data);
out.flush();
```

Now we need hot-standby/ clustering implemented behind a Load Balancer.

So the Question is - When a failover happens is it by any means possible to keep the heartbeat without having to reconnect?

[EDIT-more details]
Container - Jboss 7.1
RTSP - The PayLoad is in RTSP format. [`data = "GET_PARAMETER " + m.mediaURL + " RTSP/1.0" + "\r\n" + "CSeq: " + seqNumber + "\r\n" + "Session: " + m.sessionId + "\r\n" + "Content-Length: 0\r\nContent-Type: text/parameters\r\n" + "\r\n";`]

Comment: Could you add more details? Where does this code run? What are you doing on this socket? What's the role of RTSP?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want transparent TCP connection fail over**

I am not aware of a Java libary which supports transparent fail-over for TCP connections. As TCP is stateful, this is not really easy.

A quote from [Transparent TCP connection failover](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.120.6255)

> This paper describes a system that enables the failover of a TCP server endpoint in a manner that is transparent to the clients and to the server applications. The failover can occur at any time during the lifetime of a connection. The failover is achieved by modifying the server’s TCP/IP stack. No modifications are required to the client’s TCP/IP stack, the client application or the server application. The system supports active or semi-active replication of the server

As RTSP is not bound to TCP, I would consider using UDP.

**If heart beat is not part of the actual protocol**

But there are some other possibilities

1. Use UDP for the heart beat protocol
2. Always open/close your TCP connection
3. Write your own implementation for TCP which does a reconnect under the hood in the `write` method. So you possibly need some sort of a ping request in your protocol, just to be able to check the connection.
4. Use `aspectj` to wrap `write` in the existing implementation: So you can add a before block which just checks the connection, and does a reconnection before really entering `write`. This could be complicated, since `java.*` or `javax.*` are involved.

If it has to be fast, I would opt for UDP.

If your hear beat frequency is not that high, you could always open/close your TCP connection.

If you have enough/full control over the system, but you need to maintain the notion of an "open" connection, you can use option 3 to mimick an "open" connection.

If other systems not under your control are involved, use `aspectj`. This is a hack, because you cannot easily weave `java.*` or `javax.*`

Comment: 1.The interface that i will be talking to is TCP and cannot be changed to UDP. 2. The frequency you mentioned is less then a minute. 3. Also i am interested in knowing whose performance is better a) Open 1 client Socket and use it for multiple transactions or open separate Sockets for each transaction

Comment: What is the frequency exactly: 1s or 5s? If it's 10s, open/close should be fine. An open socket should be faster, but the question is: Is open/close fast *enough*? I would just try it.

Comment: in less than a minute i have to do "GET_PARAMETER" or "PING" to keep the session alive. And regarding the Socket operation we are looking to support 4000 concurrent transactions [SETUP&PLAY, PLAY, PAUSE, GET_PARAMETER]

Comment: Do we have some confusion regarding "client connection keep alive" and "heart beat for the cluster management"?

Comment: the heartbeat(PING) is for the session that i will create with "SETUP". The constraint is if the streamer(the other side of the TCP tunnel) doesn't get a PING within 1 minute it will consider that something has gone wrong and hence may initiate a "TEARDOWN".